# Unable to install Jenkins on Minikube using Helm due to the permission on mac

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I`vw tried to install jenkins on minikube according this article
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/

When I type `kubectl logs pod/jenkins-0 init -n jenkins`
I get

```
disable Setup Wizard
/var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh: 4: /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state: Permission denied
```

I almost sure that I have some problems with file system on mac.

I did not create serviceAccount from article because helm have not seen it and returns error.

Instead of it I changed in jenkins-values.yaml

```
serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: jenkins
  annotations: {}
```

Then I tried set next values to 0. It have no affect.

```
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
```

Addition info:
kubectl get all -n jenkins

```
NAME            READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
pod/jenkins-0   0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7          15m

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/jenkins         ClusterIP   10.104.114.29    <none>        8080/TCP    15m
service/jenkins-agent   ClusterIP   10.104.207.201   <none>        50000/TCP   15m

NAME                       READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/jenkins   0/1     15m
```

Also tried to use different directories for volume live /Volumes/data and add 777 permissions to it.

Comment: Hello, I've used the setup mentioned from the docs and everything worked correctly. Could you tell more about your setup? Especially could you include the `jenkins-volume.yaml` referenced in the docs? Have you changed anything there? Also, which `--driver` are you using with your `minikube`?

Comment: Yes, I am using minikube.

Finally I have only one change from docs 

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  # The name of the service account is autogenerated by default
  name: jenkins
  annotations: {}

As I mentioned, with setup of service-account from docs, statefulset was unable to see it.

Comment: I have a difficulty to understand your comment. Could you please tell if you actually fixed your setup and it's working correctly? Also, please take a [look on this documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/#macos) regarding different `--drivers` used in `minikube` on MacOS.

Comment: It`s not resolved. I am just using it without persistent volume. I want to remake the chart for helm.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple potentials in here, but there is a solution without switching to `runAsUser 0` (which breaks security assessments).

The folder `/data/jenkins-volume` is created as root by default, with a 755 permission set so you can't create persistent data in this dir with the default jenkins build.

- To fix this, enter minikube with `$ minikube ssh` and run: `$ chown 1000:1000 /data/jenkins-volume`

The other thing that could be biting you (after fixing the folder permissions) is SELinux policies, when you are running your Kubernetes on a RHEL based OS.

- To fix this: `$ chcon -R -t svirt_sandbox_file_t /data/jenkins-volume`

Comment: If you are using minikube, be sure to enter the minikube context before applying the permissions by running `$ minikube ssh` first!

Answer (score 1):

It was resolved

I just set  runAsUser to 0 everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

runAsUser to 0 everywhere worked, but this not the ideal solution due to potential security issues. Good for dev environment but not for prod.